# autofac Exception type: DependencyResolutionException

Tags: exception, autofac

For some reason, I get exception during instantiation of the home controller. I am very puzzled by it. I am thinking that may be it is caused by the different life time scope of the different dependencies - `InstancePerDependency` and `SingleInstance`.

using: Autofac.4.0.0

In my Register(). I have:

```cs
builder.Register(x => new DepositEligibilityService()).As<IDepositEligibilityService>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.Register(x => new SemanticExceptionManager()).As<IExceptionManager>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(x => new SemanticLoggingManager()).As<ILoggingManager>().SingleInstance();
```

and

```cs
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;

    LoginInfo _loginInfo;

    public HomeController(IDepositEligibilityService depositEligibilityService, IExceptionManager exceptionManager, ILoggingManager loggingManager):base(depositEligibilityService, exceptionManager, loggingManager)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I sometimes get an exception like the following:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: DependencyResolutionException 
    Exception message: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = HomeController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [DepositEligibility.Web.Controllers.HomeController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(DepositEligibility.Web.Services.IDepositEligibilityService, Gdot.Services.SemanticLogging.Interfaces.IExceptionManager, Gdot.Services.SemanticLogging.Interfaces.ILoggingManager)' on type 'HomeController'. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)

An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(DepositEligibility.Web.Services.IDepositEligibilityService, Gdot.Services.SemanticLogging.Interfaces.IExceptionManager, Gdot.Services.SemanticLogging.Interfaces.ILoggingManager)' on type 'HomeController'. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (See inner exception for details.)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DepositEligibility.Web.Controllers.BaseController..ctor(IDepositEligibilityService depositEligibilityService, IExceptionManager exceptionManager, ILoggingManager loggingManage)
   at DepositEligibility.Web.Controllers.HomeController..ctor(IDepositEligibilityService depositEligibilityService, IExceptionManager exceptionManager, ILoggingManager loggingManager)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
```

Comment: can you share code from the `BaseController`, especially the constructor and its body? also the constructor body of `HomeController` would be nice

Comment: The key really is the message in that inner exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DepositEligibility.Web.Controllers.BaseController..ctor(IDepositEligibilityService depositEligibilityService, IExceptionManager exceptionManager, ILoggingManager loggingManage)`

Comment: Will maxing InstancePerDependency and SingleInstance have a bad effect there?

Comment: How to add more code into my question?